# concatenate several lines in one with a delimiter with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to concatenate string on several lines into one according to an ID. I use the library pandas (python 3).

```
val   id
Cat   1
Tiger 2
Ball  3
Bat   1
bill  2
dog   1

l = []
a = 0
while a < lendata:
    if df["id"][a] == 1:
        if a != 0:
            df["val"][tmp] = ' '.join(l)
            l = []
        tmp = a
        l.append(df["val"][a])
    else:
        l.append(df["val"][a])
    a += 1
```

It works with loops.
i need this result,

```
val
Cat Tiger Ball
Bat bill
dog
```

not a group by

*Question:* Do you know how to do it with pandas functions?
Thanks.

Comment: IIUC `df.groupby('id').val.apply(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: Btw, I understand you probably just got into `pandas`, but use of nested `for/if` loops is slow compared to the available pandas function. Invest some time to learn pandas and for 90% of your problems, pandas provides a solution for them in terms of functions/methods.

Comment: @piRSquared we misunderstood, check his expected output

Comment: @jb255 You should probably explain why the particular rows of `id` define a group.  I'm guessing the consecutive nature is what does it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you can now understand why it is essential to show the expected result and to provide a true [mcve] that others can just copy and paste :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Staying in pandas:

```
df['group'] = (df['id'] == 1).cumsum()
df.groupby('group')['val'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

```
   id             val
0   1  Cat Tiger Ball
1   2        Bat bill
2   3             dog
```

The first line defines groups according to your definition. The second line is a standard groupby operation.

Comment: You mind if I add dataframe to your answer? I was reproducing the same answer might as well add it to yours

Comment: Or `df.groupby((df['id'] == 1).cumsum())['val'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: I actually had exactly that answer, but it was too close to IanS his answer to post as a new answer @jezrael

Answer (score 3):

You can also create an array like so :

```
a = np.array(range(len(df)))
```

Then you create a third column which equals to your id minus the previous array. This third column will show you which val are together.

```
df['regroup'] = df['id'].subtract(a)
```

Out:

```
id  val regroup
0   1   Cat 1
1   2   Tiger   1
2   3   Ball    1
3   1   Bat -2
```

You can now use a group by to have your desired output :

```
In [1] : df.groupby(['regroup'])['val'].apply(' '.join)
Out[1] : regroup
-2               Bat 
 1    Cat Tiger Ball
```

Comment: Interesting solution, quite creative!

Comment: Quite elegant! You could also do it in one line: `df['id'].subtract(np.arange(len(df)))`...

Answer (score 2):

#### With `np.split`

- Use `np.diff` and find where those differences are less than zero
- `np.split` the `val` column at those positions

---

```
[*map(' '.join, np.split(df.val, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(df.id) < 0) + 1))]

['Cat Tiger Ball', 'Bat']
```

---

```
pd.Series([*map(' '.join, np.split(df.val, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(df.id) < 0) + 1))])

0    Cat Tiger Ball
1               Bat
dtype: object
```

---

#### Combined Wisdom

Using [IanS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56343782/2336654)'s idea to check where `id` is equal to `1`

```
[*map(' '.join, np.split(df.val, np.flatnonzero(df.id == 1)[1:]))]
```

Comment: You're going to scare newcomers!

Comment: Should we add "Don't contribute scary answers" to the 'Welcome Wagon' policy? @IanS

Comment: On the other hand it's always nice to watch some nice numpy-fu ;)

Comment: @jb255 Don't feel any obligation to accept my answer because I was first.  If IanS's  answer suits you better, please accept his.  If you like my answer better than by all means do what you like (-: